# Is there a PowerShell Get-Content Function to extract line based on the first character?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, command-line-tool

I am trying to extract each line from a CSV that has over 1million (1,000,000) lines, where the first character is a `1`.

The `1` in this case, refers to the 1st line of a log. There are several different logs in this file, and I need the first line from all of them. Problem is (as you could understand) `1` is not unique, and can appear in any of the 12 'columns' of data I have in this CSV

Essentially, I would like to extract them all to a new CSV file as well, for further break down.

I know it sounds simple enough, but I cannot seem to get the information I need.

I have searched **StackOverflow**, **Microsoft**, **Google** and my own Tech Team.

`PS: Get-Content 'C:\Users\myfiles\Desktop\massivelogs.csv' | Select-String "1" | Out-File "extractedlogs.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer is that you must use `Select-String '^1` in order to restrict matching to the start (`^`) of each input line.

However, a much faster solution is to use the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) with the -File` option:

```
$inFile = 'C:\Users\myfiles\Desktop\massivelogs.csv' 
$outFile = 'extractedlogs.csv'
& { switch -File $inFile -Wildcard { '1*' { $_ } } } | Set-Content $outFile
```

Note, however, that the output file won't be a true CSV file, because it will lack a header row.

Also, note that `Set-Content` applies an edition-specific default character encoding (the active ANSI code page in Windows PowerShell, BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell Core); use `-Encoding` as needed.

Using `-Wildcard` with a wildcard pattern (`1*`) speeds things up slightly, compared to `-Regex` with `^1`.